# Flutter - Using WebView Widget Globally in App

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-inappwebview

What I want?

I have created a Custom Widget which loads WebView with a root url (Ex. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
I want to load webview only once when user opens up the app & I want to change the params for URL when user open another screen in app without loading the webview from scratch.

What I've tried?

I have used [flutter_in_app_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) Package for this.

```
Widget _loadPages() {
    return InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
        url: Uri.parse('www.example.com'),
      ),
      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          clearCache: true,
          cacheEnabled: true,
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          supportZoom: false,
          userAgent: Platform.isIOS ? "iPhone" : "Android",
        ),
        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
            useHybridComposition: true,
            clearSessionCache: true,
            offscreenPreRaster: true),
      ),
      onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, Uri? url) {
        _webViewController = controller;
      },
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
        _webViewController = controller;
        await _webViewController.loadUrl(
            urlRequest: URLRequest(
                url: Uri.parse('www.example.com')));
      },
      onConsoleMessage:
          (InAppWebViewController controller, ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        print('consoleMessage ----- ${consoleMessage.message}');
      },
    );
  }
```

```
 void navigate(){
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherScreen(widget:_loadPages)),
    );
  }
```

I have added code to load instance of WebView on HomePage & passed the instance to another screen & changed the URL.

Comment: One way would be to load the webview at the app launch and then pass the controller around. You must not dispose the controller if you want to use it subsequently

Comment: I've not tried passing the controller, will surely try that way.